# DEAR Magento Integration Error

Tags: magento-1.9

Our client wants to integrate DEAR Inventory with Magento. We have set up the web service user and role on Magento and completed the setup on the DEAR side but when we try to import the products from Magento to DEAR we get the following error:

Failed to load products/options: CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'catalogProductList'.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and can someone help to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue in the future:

Something I never checked was whether the WSDL was set to WS-I compliance mode. Once I updated the setting the API calls worked as expected.